# make a function globally available via webpack

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, webpack

I have a `.ts` file that contains a function, and I want to compile this file into `.js` file via webpack to be loaded in `index.html`.

I need this function to be globally available in index.html, or within a module

index.html

```
<script src="./myfile.js"></scrit>
<script>
  console.log(myfunction);
// ----> error: myfunction is not defined
</scrit>


<script type="module">
  import { myfunction } from './myfile'
  console.log({myfunction})
// ----> error: requested module './myfile.js' does not provide an export named 'myfunction'
</script>
```

myfile.ts

```
export myfunction = function(){}
```

webpack.config

```
{
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: false,
    target: [ 'web', 'es5' ],
    profile: false,
    resolve: {
      roots: [Array],
      extensions: [Array],
      symlinks: false,
      modules: [Array],
      mainFields: [Array],
      plugins: [Array],
      alias: [Object]
    },
    resolveLoader: { symlinks: true, modules: [Array] },
    context: '/home/sh_eldeeb_2010/@eng-dibo/dibo/projects/ngx-cms',
    entry: {
      main: [Array],
      'polyfills-es5': [Array],
      polyfills: [Array],
      styles: [Array],
      scripts: './scripts.ts'
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
      path: './dist',
      publicPath: '',
      filename: '[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name]-es2015.js',
      crossOriginLoading: false,
      trustedTypes: 'angular#bundler',
      library: undefined,
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    watch: false,
    watchOptions: { poll: undefined, ignored: '**/$_lazy_route_resources' },
    performance: { hints: false },
    ignoreWarnings: [
      /System.import\(\) is deprecated and will be removed soon/i,
      /Failed to parse source map from/,
      /Add postcss as project dependency/
    ],
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [Array],
      noParse: /\/native-require.js$/
    },
    experiments: { syncWebAssembly: true, asyncWebAssembly: true },
    cache: false,
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [Array],
      moduleIds: 'deterministic',
      chunkIds: 'deterministic',
      emitOnErrors: false,
      runtimeChunk: 'single',
      splitChunks: [Object]
    },
    plugins: [
      [ContextReplacementPlugin],
      [DedupeModuleResolvePlugin],
      [ProgressPlugin],
      [LicenseWebpackPlugin],
      [CommonJsUsageWarnPlugin],
      [AnyComponentStyleBudgetChecker],
      [Object],
      [MiniCssExtractPlugin],
      SuppressExtractedTextChunksWebpackPlugin {},
      [NgBuildAnalyticsPlugin],
      [AngularWebpackPlugin],
      [FilterErrors]
    ],
    node: false,
    stats: {
      all: false,
      colors: true,
      hash: true,
      timings: true,
      chunks: true,
      builtAt: true,
      warnings: true,
      errors: true,
      assets: true,
      cachedAssets: true,
      ids: true,
      entrypoints: true
    },
    externals: []
  },
  entry: {
    myfile: './myfile.ts'
  }
}
```

Comment: try `export default function(){}`

Comment: Modules are different than ordinary code. A "global" function that is in a module is not global in the truly global sense. You'll have to explicitly attach it to the global object (`global` or `window`) to make that happen.

Comment: the same error occures `'./myfile.js' does not provide an export named 'default'` @johnSmith

Comment: ok, I need to access the function either globally or within the module @Pointy

Comment: It is encouraged you don't do `window.myfunction = myfunction;` and instead import it every time from a module where you need it. This way it will be removed from the final build if not used anymore.

Comment: as seen in my snipet I already try to import it as a module without success @PeterKrebs

Comment: Yes but you are still trying to export a function despite it not working. Why? Just export an object with that function in it, of which you can find example code all over. You wrote you need the function to be globally available. If you import it, it is not globally available, really. Instead of `myfunction` you can just import an object and write `MyObject.myfunction`.